# Исходный файл проинспектированного элемента (Opera)

Tags: opera

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему - дело в том, что я с помощью стандартной функции Оперы (проинспектировать элемент) посмотрел разметку страницы вместе с кодом (одна из страниц CMS). Подскажите пожалуйста - возможно ли каким-то образом узнать название файла, который отвечает за генерацию данной страницы, путь к нему или тому подобное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Максимум, что можно узнать, - это адрес сайта, плюс заголовки, которые приходят. Фактически "проинспектировать элемент" - это отображение той же страницы в другом, более удобоваримом виде. )

Comment: Спасибо. А жаль, ) я подозревал, но до последнего надеялся, что все же можна.